# How to remove the value that was initially given a variable and just keep the result obtained after been modified

Tags: javascript

I want to get the second result only because i wanted to removed the commas and spaces in between but it gives me both, the variable value and the result after been modified using methods I want to get only the result after the variable is modified here is what I have so far:

```
let alphabet = ' A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z ';
alphabet.split(",").map((val) => {
  return   alphabet += val.trim() ;
})
console.log(alphabet);
```

that is going to console out ' A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

and I only want to get: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', is there a method that i should apply to it or another way around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let alphabet = ' A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z ';
const result = alphabet.split(", ").join('')
console.log(result);
```